# Can I display a document library from another site collection as a Webpart in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-web-parts

How could I display a Document Library from another Site Collection, in Sharepoint Online.

Could I create a Custom Web part and connect to the Sharepoint API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to display files from another site (not expose them for editing), consider using the "Highlighted Content" web part on a modern page.

It allows you to pick a site to pull content from, then filter by content type, file type, and managed properties. You can use the "path" managed property to only get documents from a specific library (Path Begins with {library url}).

You will find that it is more limited than a list/library view web part in that you cannot specify which fields to display and your sort options are limited to "Most recent," "Most viewed," "Trending," and ascending or descending by a Managed property. However, it's good for quickly exposing files from another site, assuming the current user has access to view them.

Comment: Thanks @Thriggle, that works and got us on track, but like you say the display is limited. Would it be possible to specify a Custom view defined for the document library?

Comment: Not using that web part, unfortunately. If you enable custom scripts or use a modern-friendly script web part from GitHub you may able to develop your own custom view of content from the Search API or queried through the REST API, or you could try your luck creating a SharePoint Framework web part to do the same, but that'll be a significant development effort.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The embed web part can display a Document from another Site Collection. Just copy and paste the library address.

Embed web part:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a page with document library on source site and refer/add that page as page viewer webpart on destination part.

https://www.consultdolphin.com/easy-method-of-showing-lists-libraries-across-site-collections/#1542120640891-2315c938-9973

Comment: This does not work in modern layout